# Finding a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$, $B$ be groups. Find an example for a normal subgroup $C$ of $A \times B$ that is not the direct product of $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$.

I have some troubles to understand how this can be possible. If I would e.g. take $\mathbb{Z}_2 = A = B$, then $A \times B$ would be the Klein four-group. N could be chosen as $\{(1_A,1_B)\}$ with $1$ being the neutral element. But how can $A \cap C$ or $B \cap C$ be defined? How can I build an intersection of a group containing single elements (the groups A and B) with a group containing tuples (C)? What group should I pick to find an example for this? Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Recall that $A$ can be identified with $A \times \{ 1_B \} \leq A \times B$ and $B$ with $\{ 1_A \} \times B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=B= \mathbb{Z}$, $C= \{ (a,a) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

$A= \{ (a,0) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, $B= \{ (0,b) : b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Then $C \cap A = 0 = C \cap B$ and $C \neq 0$ is not the direct product of $0$ and $0$.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why $C \cap A = 0$? Might you mean $\{0\}$?

Comment: As I said above, $A=\{ (a,0) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, so $A \cap C = \{ (0,0) \}$, and the same for $B \cap C$. You will take confidence with notation going on studying group theory. When additive notation is used, brackets are often omitted, denoting with $0$ the trivial subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

The abelian additive group $\;\Bbb Z_2:=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$, and take

$$C:=\langle\;(1,1)\;\rangle\le\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2=:G$$

trivially $\;C\lhd G\;,\;\;C\neq G\;$ , but

$$C\cap\Bbb Z_2=\Bbb Z_2$$

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you explain to me why $C \cap \mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2$? In addition, isn't $0$ the neutral element for $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and should therefore be part of $C$?

Comment: Of course, @muffel: $$\langle\;(1,1)\;\rangle = \{(1,1)\,,\,(0,0)\}\;$$ so that $\; C\cap( \{0\}\times\Bbb Z_2=\{0\}\times \Bbb Z_2\;$ .